# R - gghighlight color for each line

Tags: r, ggplot2, gghighlight

I have a data frame with this format:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
  time = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
  value = c(1,3,5,2,4,6,3,5,7,1,4,7)
)
```

I want to create individual plots highlighting each `id` and with other unhighlighted `ids` shaded as grey.

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = value, color = as.factor(id))) + 
  gghighlight::gghighlight(id == 4)
```

I have looked into the `gghighlight` package which can do the highlighting for a single line. However, I am looking to have one plot for each `id (1,2,3,4,etc...)`.

Is there a smart and clever way to do this quickly? Can `facet_grid` achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `facet_wrap` and `facet_grid` work faceting on `id`.

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = value, color = as.factor(id))) + 
  gghighlight::gghighlight() +
  facet_wrap(~id)
```